# Serialization of List not giving required output

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a tried list, array and all different types

I have a list of items which is serializing just fine

in c#

```
public mySortableBindingList<Item> TransactionLines = new mySortableBindingList<Item>();
```

in vb.net

```
Public WithEvents TransactionLines As New mySortableBindingList(Of Item)
```

xml output is

```
<TransactionLines>
   <Item>
    <elements>
   </item>
   <Item>
    <elements>
   </item>
</TransactionLines>
```

my serilization method is the following

In C#

```
public string SerializeToXML<T>(T obj)
{
string XMLString = "";
try {
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    using (MemoryStream myMemStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        mySerializer.Serialize(myMemStream, obj);
        myMemStream.SeekToBegin();
        XMLString = myMemStream.ReadToEnd(Encoding.UTF8);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return XMLString;
}
```

In vb.net

```
 Public Function SerializeToXML(Of T)(ByVal obj As T) As String

        Dim XMLString As String = ""
        Try
            Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)

            Using myMemStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                mySerializer.Serialize(myMemStream, obj)
                myMemStream.SeekToBegin()
                XMLString = myMemStream.ReadToEnd(Encoding.UTF8)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return XMLString
    End Function
```

List to be serialized

c#

```
[XmlElement(Order = 17)]
public mySortableBindingList<ItemSerial> Serials = new mySortableBindingList<ItemSerial>();
```

vb.net

```
<XmlElement(Order:=17)>
Public Serials As New mySortableBindingList(Of ItemSerial)
```

This is my xml output

```
<Serials>
   <Serial>A</Serial>
   <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ExpiryDate>
   <Qty>1</Qty>
</Serials>
<Serials>
   <Serial>B</Serial>
   <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ExpiryDate>
   <Qty>1</Qty>
</Serials>
```

I need the following please explain what I can be doing wrong

```
  <Serials>
   <ItemSerial>
      <Serial>A</Serial>
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ExpiryDate>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
   </ItemSerial>
   <ItemSerial>
      <Serial>B</Serial>
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ExpiryDate>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
   </ItemSerial>
</Serials>
```

Comment: How about showing some code?

Comment: In the meantime, learn how to use the XML attributes such as `[XmlElement]` etc. to influence XML serialization in .NET: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: First off you tagged C# not VB.NET.  Second we need the classes that are being serialised.

Comment: Few general comments on your code - don't `Catch` and then just `Throw` - this will lose your stack trace. No need to `Close` your `myMemStream` - that' what the `Using` statement does. Also you need to post the code for your serialised classes.

Comment: @richard if you know how to read that the first serilization is of the list that is serilizaing properly.  While the second one is being seilizing in the same manner. So it should give the same output. Also what is the difference between vb and c# ive worked with both and they are practically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Richards answer I found that I could use XMLArray attribute which will infer that it is a list and therefore be serialized in the manner I required.

Answer (score 0):

You  really need to post the class definitions.

In any event you will need to `XmlArrayItemAttribute` to specify the element name for `ItemSerial`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

When you post code, I'll add an example.